# Import data from several workbooks in the same folder into the one I'm using and paste it vertically

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have several workbooks for regions of the world and then I want to combine them into a final workbook with all of them. In hindsight having all of the regions in the same workbook and the Final one as well would turn this into a simple task but now I want to see this through. Column 1 is untouched as it contains a formula that uses the data pulled

Since the data is supposed to not be always appending at first I "clean" my "final" workbook by clearing the values from B2 to Cells(300,27) (maximum number of rows that can be filled out)

In general I want to open the folder that my "final" workbook is on, cycle through all the workbooks in that folder

For each one that isn't my "final" workbook I want to copy the data from B2 to last row of each region workbook (which I calculate) and column 27

And paste it at the end of Final, so last row in final, offset it by one row.

Close loop

Done.

Now I am struggling a lot with not having mistakes that show up and then disappear even when I don't change anything which makes me think I'm not selecting the sheet or activating it properly.

Below I have my relatively simple code which I though would achieve what I wanted. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or which call/function am I misunderstanding that needs to be changed so I can be rid of this burden? Does it matter that the other workbooks are also macro enabled when I call. This question seems to have been answered several times already and I looked through them and tried to understand and rearrange my code accordingly but even though it helped a lot my code still isn't working as intended every single time. Please help and thank you for your time

I have tried doing this

```
     Sub Test()

     Dim wb As Workbook
     Dim ThisBook As Workbook
     Dim Region As Workbook
     Dim LRregion As Long
     Dim LRfinal As Long
     Dim OpenBook As Workbook

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Set ThisBook = ThisWorkbook

     'Important data that will never be missing is on column 4 so I use that as an indicator
     LRfinal=ThisWorkbook.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

     ThisWorkbook.Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(LRfinal,27)).ClearContents


     For each wb in ThisWorkbook.Path

     If wb.Name <> "Final"
      
         Set OpenBook = Application.wb.Open

            'All of these only have 1 sheet
            LRregion = Openbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        
            Openbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LRregion, 27)).Copy
        
        
            LRfinal = ThisWorkbook.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(LRfinal+1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
            OpenBook.Close False

End if

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There are a number of pretty basic issues with your code, most of which could be resolved by looking at the similar posts here on SO.  Eg `Cells` and `Range` are properties of a `worksheet`, not `workbook`.  `For each wb in ThisWorkbook.Path` is not how you loop over files in a folder.  `Application.wb.Open` is not valid syntax.  Please focus on one *specific* issue with your code when asking here - a good start is to make sure your code compiles before you try to run it.

Comment: Sounds like it would easier to use Power Query - _Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder_.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. So if I'm calling the Cells or Range properties I should always call  Workbook.Sheet.Cells/Range is that it? Because these calls have been working sometimes, just like the code sometimes works and does part of what it's supposed to do as I mentioned above. I've also tried the "for each" cycle with Application.Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\*.xlsm") but it also didn't work